# Алгоритм генерации смежных границ таблиц в эмуляторах терминала

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, консоль, utf-8, интерфейс

Вопрос ко всем полиглотам! Не только знающих JavaScript. Пойдет любой язык программирования, просто JavaScript самый удобный при использовании на SO.

Пытаюсь написать небольшой тренажер для Vim. С помощью таблицы символов UTF-8
я отрисовываю в эмуляторе терминала xterm вот такую таблицу:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ┌─────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┬─────┐ ║ 
║ │ Esc │F1 │F2 │F3 │F4 │F5 │F6 │F7 │F8 │F9 │F10│F11│F12│Ins │PrSc│ Del │ ║ 
║ ├───┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼────┼────┼─────┤ ║ 
║ │`~ │ 1! │ 2@ │ 3# │ 4$ │ 5% │ 6^ │ 7& │ 8* │ 9( │ 0) │ -_ │ =+ │ BkSp│ ║ 
║ ├───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬────┤ ║ 
║ │Tab │ Q  │ W  │ E  │ R  │ T  │ Y  │ U  │ I  │ O  │ P  │ [  │ ]  │ \| │ ║ 
║ ├────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴────┤ ║ 
║ │CpsLck│ A  │ S  │ D  │ F  │ G  │ H  │ J  │ K  │ L  │ ;: │ '" │ Enter │ ║ 
║ ├──────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴───────┤ ║ 
║ │Shift   │ Z  │ X  │ C  │ V  │ B  │ N  │ M  │ ,< │ .> │ /? │ Shift    │ ║ 
║ ├─────┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴────┴────┴────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬┬─┴───┬┴────┬─────┤ ║ 
║ │Ctrl │ Fn │Win │Alt │                   │Alt │Ctrl││PgUp │ Up  │PgDn │ ║ 
║ └─────┴────┴────┴────┴─────────────────┬─┴──┬─┴──┬─┘├─────┼─────┼─────┤ ║ 
║                                        │Home│End │  │Left │Down │Right│ ║ 
║                                        └────┴────┘  └─────┴─────┴─────┘ ║ 
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Вскоре я понял, что по ходу работы программы мне необходимо выделять некоторые
ячейки таблицы по их смежным границам, например как тут:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ┌─────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┬─────┐ ║ 
║ │ Esc │F1 │F2 │F3 │F4 │F5 │F6 │F7 │F8 │F9 │F10│F11│F12│Ins │PrSc│ Del │ ║ 
║ ├───┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼────┼────┼─────┤ ║ 
║ │`~ │ 1! │ 2@ │ 3# │ 4$ │ 5% │ 6^ │ 7& │ 8* │ 9( │ 0) │ -_ │ =+ │ BkSp│ ║ 
║ ├───┴┲━━━┷┳━━━┷┱───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬────┤ ║ 
║ │Tab ┃ Q  ┃ W  ┃ E  │ R  │ T  │ Y  │ U  │ I  │ O  │ P  │ [  │ ]  │ \| │ ║ 
║ ├────┺━┯━━┻━┯━━┹─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┲━━┷━┱──┴─┬──┴────┤ ║ 
║ │CpsLck│ A  │ S  │ D  │ F  │ G  │ H  │ J  │ K  │ L  ┃ ;: ┃ '" │ Enter │ ║ 
║ ┢━━━━━━┷━┱──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┺━┯━━┹─┬──┴───────┤ ║ 
║ ┃Shift   ┃ Z  │ X  │ C  │ V  │ B  │ N  │ M  │ ,< │ .> │ /? │ Shift    │ ║ 
║ ┡━━━━━┯━━┹─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴────┴────┴────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬┬─┴───┬┴────┬─────┤ ║ 
║ │Ctrl │ Fn │Win │Alt │                   │Alt │Ctrl││PgUp │ Up  │PgDn │ ║ 
║ └─────┴────┴────┴────┴─────────────────┬─┴──┬─┴──┬─┘├─────┼─────┼─────┤ ║ 
║                                        │Home│End │  │Left │Down │Right│ ║ 
║                                        └────┴────┘  └─────┴─────┴─────┘ ║ 
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Здесь выделены ячейки "Q", "W", ";", "Shift". Первая мысль, которая пришла
на ум - захардкодить всё к чертовой бабушке. Но, очевидно, что это будет
очень непросто, так как ячейки имеют разные размеры и формы, а самое главное -
разные положения соседских ячеек. Да и потом, мне хотелось бы предоставить
возможность пользователю с помощью конфигов составлять схемы своих раскладок.
Но как это сделать - в голове ни единой мысли.

Работая с такой псевдо-графикой, таблица символов UTF-8 должна быть всегда
под рукой. Но, при работе с символами рисования таблиц, всё равно возникают
сложности поиска того или иного символа в таблице. И с опытом постоянных
наблюдений таблицы символов ситуация меняется только в худшую сторону,
так как поиск нужных символов превращается нудную рутину. Мои пытки
понять логику распределения порядка символов рисования привели меня к
логическому утверждению - символы рисования внесены в таблицу UFT-8 в
случайно-хаотичном порядке.

Через какое-то время я придумал как мне систематизировать порядок
символов, чтобы быстро находить нужный мне символ даже не заглядывая в
саму таблицу. Я даже написал функцию `draw()`, которая принимает восьми-битное
целое число и возвращает нужный мне символ. Каждый символ рисования состоит
из 1-4 отростков направленных из центра в 4 стороны. Если пронумеровать биты
числа так, чтобы впереди были старшие биты, а в конце младшие (76543210),
то первая пара бит (76) соответствует отростку в северном направлении,
вторая пара бит (54) соответствует отростку в восточном направлении,
третья пара бит (32) соответствует отростку в южном направлении,
и последняя пара бит (01) соответствует отростку в западном направлении.
Очень легко запомнить, прям как в правилах border в CSS по часовой стрелке:
вверх, вправо, вниз, влево. Каждая пара бит может хранить в себе значение
от 0 до 3 (Карл!), где `0` соответствует тому, что отростка в эту сторону
нет, `1` соответствует отростку с тонкой линией, `2` соответствует отростку
с жирной линией и `3` соответствует отростку с двойной линией.

Код функции на языке JavaScript можно наблюдать ниже вместе с небольшой
демкой её работы.

```js
/**
 * @var Unicode Box Draw Map
 * @usedBy draw()
 */
const boxDraw = new Map([
  [  1, 116],[  2, 120],[  4, 119],[  5,  16],[  6,  17],[  7,  85],
  [  8, 123],[  9,  18],[ 10,  19],[ 13,  86],[ 15,  87],[ 16, 118],
  [ 17,   0],[ 18, 126],[ 20,  12],[ 21,  44],[ 22,  45],[ 24,  14],
  [ 25,  48],[ 26,  49],[ 28,  83],[ 29, 101],[ 32, 122],[ 33, 124],
  [ 34,   1],[ 36,  13],[ 37,  46],[ 38,  47],[ 40,  15],[ 41,  50],
  [ 42,  51],[ 51,  80],[ 52,  82],[ 55, 100],[ 60,  84],[ 63, 102],
  [ 64, 117],[ 65,  24],[ 66,  25],[ 67,  91],[ 68,   2],[ 69,  36],
  [ 70,  37],[ 71,  97],[ 72, 125],[ 73,  39],[ 74,  42],[ 80,  20],
  [ 81,  52],[ 82,  53],[ 84,  28],[ 85,  60],[ 86,  61],[ 88,  31],
  [ 89,  65],[ 90,  69],[ 96,  21],[ 97,  54],[ 98,  55],[100,  29],
  [101,  62],[102,  63],[104,  34],[105,  70],[106,  72],[112,  88],
  [115, 103],[116,  94],[119, 106],[128, 121],[129,  26],[130,  27],
  [132, 127],[133,  38],[134,  41],[136,   3],[137,  40],[138,  43],
  [144,  22],[145,  56],[146,  57],[148,  30],[149,  64],[150,  67],
  [152,  32],[153,  66],[154,  73],[160,  23],[161,  58],[162,  59],
  [164,  33],[165,  68],[166,  71],[168,  35],[169,  74],[170,  75],
  [193,  92],[195,  93],[204,  81],[205,  98],[207,  99],[208,  89],
  [209, 104],[220,  95],[221, 107],[240,  90],[243, 105],[252,  96],
  [255, 108],
]);

/**
 * @function draw
 * @param {Number} code Must be integer in range [0-255]
 * @returns {String}
 */
function draw(code) {
  return !code ? ' ' : boxDraw.has(code) ? String.fromCharCode(boxDraw.get(code) + 0x2500) : null;
}


const getValue = () =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked')]
    .map(input => +input.value)
    .reduce((a, v, i) => ((a |= v << (6 - 2 * i)), a), 0);

const updateOutput = () => {
  const value = getValue();
  document.getElementById('output-bin').value = `draw(0b${value.toString(2).padStart(8, 0)})`;
  document.getElementById('output-dec').value = `draw(${value})`;
  document.getElementById('output-char').value = draw(value) ? `${draw(value)}` : '☒';
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.right .val .pair')
    .forEach(
      (pair, i) =>
        (pair.innerHTML = [...((value >> (6 - 2 * i)) & 3).toString(2).padStart(2, 0)].map(c => `<b>${c}</b>`).join``)
    );
};

document.forms[0].oninput = updateOutput;

const onfocus = e => e.target.select();

document.getElementById('output-bin').onfocus = onfocus;
document.getElementById('output-dec').onfocus = onfocus;
document.getElementById('output-char').onfocus = onfocus;
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Monaco;
  font-size: 10vh;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.half {  flex: 1;}
.legend {  display: flex;  flex-flow: row nowrap;  justify-content: space-evenly;}
input[type='radio'] {  display: none;}

label {
  border: 0.1vw solid #000;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 15vh;
  padding: 0 0.6vw 0 0.6vw;
  border-radius: 0.3vw;
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  border: 0.1vw solid #eba309;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1vw #eba309, 0 0 1vw #eba309;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.3vw #eba309;
  color: #624404;
}

.char {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.2rem #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.1rem #000;
}

.pair {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 0.6vw;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* line-height: 0.7em; */
  padding: 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw 0.2vw;
}

.pair b {
  padding: 0 0.3vw 0 0.3vw;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 0.3vw;
  margin: 0.2vw;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: inline-block;
  /* line-height: 0.7em; */
}
.legend,.math,.radio-group {  height: 18vh;  font-size: 12vh;  line-height: 15vh;}
.left {  flex: 1;}
form {  display: flex;  flex-flow: row wrap;}form div {  width: 50%;}

.no-symbol {
  margin: 3vh 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.4em;
  display: block;
  width: 6vw;
  height: 8vh;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

.output-group {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3vh;
}
#output-bin {  width: 44vw;}
#output-dec {  width: 24vw;}
#output-bin,
#output-dec,
#output-char {
  font-size: 12vh;
  font-family: Monaco;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1vh;
}

.right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: '1 n 3' 'w c e' ' 7 s 9';
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  max-width: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vw;
}
.north {  grid-area: n;}
.east {  grid-area: e;}
.south {  grid-area: s;}
.west {  grid-area: w;}
.center {  grid-area: c;}
.north,.south,.east,.west {  display: flex;}
.north,.south {  flex-flow: column nowrap;}
.east,.west {  flex-flow: row nowrap;}
.north .var,.west .var,.south .val,.east .val {  order: 1;}
.north .val,.west .val,.south .var,.east .var {  order: 2;}

.right .var,
.right .val {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

#output-char {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="half left">
  <div class="legend">
    <span class="char">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>0</b></span>
    <span class="char">┼</span>
    <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>1</b></span>
    <span class="char">╋</span>
    <span class="pair"><b>1</b><b>0</b></span>
    <span class="char">╬</span>
    <span class="pair"><b>1</b><b>1</b></span>
    <span class="char">☒</span>
    <span class="no-symbol">No Symbol</span>
  </div>
  <div class="math">
    <span class="var">a</span>
    <span class="action">&lt;&lt;</span>
    <span class="const">6</span>
    <span class="action">|</span>
    <span class="var">b</span>
    <span class="action">&lt;&lt;</span>
    <span class="const">4</span>
    <span class="action">|</span>
    <span class="var">c</span>
    <span class="action">&lt;&lt;</span>
    <span class="const">2</span>
    <span class="action">|</span>
    <span class="var">d</span>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <span class="static">a =</span>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="0" id="a-0" /><label for="a-0">0</label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="1" id="a-1" checked /><label for="a-1">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="2" id="a-2" /><label for="a-2">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="3" id="a-3" /><label for="a-3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <span class="static">b =</span>
      <input type="radio" name="b" value="0" id="b-0" /><label for="b-0">0</label>
      <input type="radio" name="b" value="1" id="b-1" checked /><label for="b-1">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="b" value="2" id="b-2" /><label for="b-2">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="b" value="3" id="b-3" /><label for="b-3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <span class="static">c =</span>
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="0" id="c-0" /><label for="c-0">0</label>
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="1" id="c-1" checked /><label for="c-1">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="2" id="c-2" /><label for="c-2">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="c" value="3" id="c-3" /><label for="c-3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <span class="static">d =</span>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="0" id="d-0" /><label for="d-0">0</label>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="1" id="d-1" checked /><label for="d-1">1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="2" id="d-2" /><label for="d-2">2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="d" value="3" id="d-3" /><label for="d-3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="output-group">
      <input id="output-bin" type="text" value="draw(0b01010101)" readonly />
      <input id="output-dec" type="text" value="draw(85)" readonly />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="half right">
  <div class="north">
    <div class="var">a</div>
    <div class="val">
      <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>1</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="east">
    <div class="var">b</div>
    <div class="val">
      <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>1</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="south">
    <div class="var">c</div>
    <div class="val">
      <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>1</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="west">
    <div class="var">d</div>
    <div class="val">
      <span class="pair"><b>0</b><b>1</b></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" id="output-char" value="┼" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```

К сожалению, других идей кроме написания этой функции мне найти не удалось.
Да и в целом прогресса никакого нет. Всю теоретическую часть вопроса,
такую как [управляющие последовательности Xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) я вроде освоил.
Но алгоритм генерации смежных границ ячеек в таблицах псевдо-графики
терминальных эмуляторов я придумать совсем не могу. Если здесь есть люди с опытом работы с графикой в эмуляторах терминала, я буду рад любым идеям.

Чтобы вопрос был с четкой задачей, которую можно выполнить или не выполнить надо бы обозначить условия. Язык предпочтительнее JavaScript. В простом теге `<pre>` есть псевдо-таблица клавиатуры. У окна есть слушатели keydown и keyup. Необходимо дописать код слушателей таким образом, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу, она выделялась жирной границей в таблице клавиатуры, и, когда клавиша отпускалась, граница клавиши переходила в исходный вид. Для примера сделаю Win, Shift, Ctrl и Alt.

```js
window.onkeydown = updateKbd;
window.onkeyup = updateKbd;

function updateKbd(event){
const { ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey } = event;
const content = [[/&/g,'&amp;'],[/</g,'&lt;'],[/>/g,'&gt;']].reduce((str,[rx,rp])=>str.replace(rx,rp), pre.textContent);
const modifiers = [
[ 698, shiftKey ? '┢━━━━━━┷━┱' : '├──────┴─┬',],
[ 757, shiftKey ? '┲━━┷━━━━━━━┪': '┬──┴───────┤',], 
[ 775, shiftKey ? `┃Shift   ┃` : '│Shift   │',],
[ 840, shiftKey ? `┃ Shift    ┃` : '│ Shift    │',],
[ 858, shiftKey && !ctrlKey ? '┡' : !shiftKey && ctrlKey ? '┢' : shiftKey && ctrlKey ? '┣' : '├',],
[ 859, shiftKey || ctrlKey ? '━━━━━' : '─────',],
[ 864, shiftKey && !ctrlKey ? '┯' : !shiftKey && ctrlKey? '┱' : shiftKey && ctrlKey ? '┳' : '┬',],
[ 865, shiftKey ? '━━┹' : '──┴',],
[ 869, metaKey ? '┲━━┷━' : '┬──┴─',],
[ 874, metaKey && !altKey ? '┱' : !metaKey && altKey ? '┲' : metaKey && altKey ? '┳' : '┬',],
[ 875, altKey ? '━━┷━┱' : '──┴─┬',],
[ 899, altKey ? '┲━━┷━' : '┬──┴─',],
[ 904, altKey && !ctrlKey ? '┱' : !altKey && ctrlKey ? '┲' : altKey && ctrlKey ? '┳' : '┬',],
[ 905, ctrlKey ? '━━┷━┱' : '──┴─┬',],
[ 917, shiftKey ? '┺━━━━┯━━━━━┩' : '┴────┬─────┤' ,],
[ 935, ctrlKey ? `┃Ctrl ┃` : '│Ctrl │',],
[ 946, metaKey ? `┃Win ` : '│Win ',],
[ 951, metaKey || altKey ? '┃' : '│',],
[ 952, altKey ? `Alt ┃` : 'Alt │',],
[ 976, altKey ? `┃Alt ` : '│Alt ',],
[ 981, altKey || ctrlKey ? '┃' : '│',],
[ 982, ctrlKey ? `Ctrl┃` : 'Ctrl│',],
[1012, ctrlKey ? '┗━━━━━┹' : '└─────┴',],
[1023, metaKey ? '┺━━━━' : '┴────',],  
[1028, metaKey && !altKey ? '┹' : !metaKey && altKey ? '┺' : metaKey && altKey ? '┻' : '┴',], 
[1029, altKey ? '━━━━┹' : '────┴',], 
[1053, altKey ? '┺━━┯━' : '┴──┬─',], 
[1058, altKey && ! ctrlKey ? '┹' : !altKey && ctrlKey ? '┺' : altKey && ctrlKey ? '┻' : '┴',],  // TODO
[1059, ctrlKey ? '━━┯━┛' : '──┬─┘',], 
];
let pos = 0, out = '';
for(let [mpos,str] of modifiers){
  out += content.substring(pos,mpos)+str;
  pos = mpos + str.length;
}
out+=content.substring(pos);
pre.innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<pre id="pre">
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ┌─────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┬─────┐ ║ 
║ │ Esc │F1 │F2 │F3 │F4 │F5 │F6 │F7 │F8 │F9 │F10│F11│F12│Ins │PrSc│ Del │ ║ 
║ ├───┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼───┴┬──┴─┬─┴──┬┴───┼────┼────┼─────┤ ║ 
║ │`~ │ 1! │ 2@ │ 3# │ 4$ │ 5% │ 6^ │ 7&amp; │ 8* │ 9( │ 0) │ -_ │ =+ │ BkSp│ ║ 
║ ├───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬───┴┬────┤ ║ 
║ │Tab │ Q  │ W  │ E  │ R  │ T  │ Y  │ U  │ I  │ O  │ P  │ [  │ ]  │ \| │ ║ 
║ ├────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴────┤ ║ 
║ │CpsLck│ A  │ S  │ D  │ F  │ G  │ H  │ J  │ K  │ L  │ ;: │ '" │ Enter │ ║ 
║ ├──────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴───────┤ ║ 
║ │Shift   │ Z  │ X  │ C  │ V  │ B  │ N  │ M  │ ,&lt; │ .&gt; │ /? │ Shift    │ ║ 
║ ├─────┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬──┴────┴────┴────┴─┬──┴─┬──┴─┬┬─┴───┬┴────┬─────┤ ║ 
║ │Ctrl │ Fn │Win │Alt │                   │Alt │Ctrl││PgUp │ Up  │PgDn │ ║ 
║ └─────┴────┴────┴────┴─────────────────┬─┴──┬─┴──┬─┘├─────┼─────┼─────┤ ║ 
║                                        │Home│End │  │Left │Down │Right│ ║ 
║                                        └────┴────┘  └─────┴─────┴─────┘ ║ 
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
</pre>
```

Comment: В последнем сниппете геометрия раскладки ломается, это баг просто или при замене символов такие смещения неизбежны? А по-другому выделять клавишу не вариант?

Comment: @Leonid тут вероятно дело в шрифте, для таких целей надо использовать monospace шрифт, где размеры всех символов одинаковые, в сниппете автор как раз задает один вроде бы такой шрифт, если в инспекторе убрать Andale Mono шрифт и оставить дефолтные стили для <pre>, то всё становится ок

Comment: отдельно посмотрел на xubuntu как отображается, проблема вероятно в наличии шрифта в ОС (или в браузере на конкретной ОС), на винде с Andale Mono плохо, на xubuntu хорошо

Comment: Это баг рендера, выключил переопределение шрифтов. У меня на макос  `monospace` какой-то не моноширный.

Comment: @Slavic Проблема еще может быть в том, что рендерер шрифтов может брать недостающие  символы utf-8 из разных других шрифтов. Моноширные шрифты могут быть единой ширины но с единой высотой быть не обязаны.)) Из-за этого на отдельных символах могут быть какие-то палочки короче, где-то длинее, где-то шире и все это как-бы в одном шрифте... При этом в терминале почему-то любой шрифт выглядит красиво.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`makeKeyboard` создаёт клавитуру. Клавиатура позволяет создавать кнопки с произвольными надписями и границей. Граница может быть любым многоугольником со сторонами параллельными осям. Координаты соответствуют прямоугольной решётке из символов. Начало координат в левом верхем углу.

Каждая кнопка может быть нажата (`press`) и отпущена (`release`).

Клавиатура хранит состояние для отображения но сама рисовать себя не умеет. За рисование отвечает `makeScreen`, который отображает клавиатуру в элементе `pre`.

Основная функциональность закончилась. `makeKeyboardBuilder` делает создание клавиатуры более удобным, но не использует все возможности клавиатуры, например неквадратные кнопки.

Конфигурация клавиатуры и привязка кнопок к событиям сделана кодом в `main`. Это самая грязная часть. Нормальное решение было бы создавать кнопки по одной и немедленно привязывать их к событиям. К сожалению, "правильный" подход раздует пример и отвлечёт внимание от `клавиатуры` и `экрана`.

```js
const updateElement = (element, attributes) => {
    for (const key in attributes) {
        element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
    }
};

const createElement = (parent_, tag, attributes) => {
    const element = document.createElement(tag);
    updateElement(element, attributes);
    parent_.appendChild(element);
    return element;
};

const createTextNode = (parent_, text) => {
    const node = document.createTextNode(text);
    parent_.appendChild(node);
    return node;
};

const makeKeyboard = () => {
    const makeCell = () => {
        let char_ = ' ';
        const pseudographics =
            ' ╷╻╴┐┒╸┑┓' +
            '╵│╽┘┤┧┙┥┪' +
            '╹╿┃┚┦┨┛┩┫' +
            '╶┌┎─┬┰╾┭┱' +
            '└├┟┴┼╁┵┽╅' +
            '┖┞┠┸╀╂┹╃╉' +
            '╺┍┏╼┮┲━┯┳' +
            '┕┝┢┝┾╆┷┿╈' +
            '┗┡┣┺╄╇┻╇╋'
        ;

        const weights = [0, 0, 0, 0];
        const style = () =>
            weights.reduce((a, b) => 3 * a  + Math.min(b, 2), 0);
        const dirs = {'r': 0, 'u': 1, 'l': 2, 'd': 3};

        return {
            'setChar': c => char_ = c,
            'getChar': () => char_,
            'setLine': dir => {
                weights[dirs[dir]] = 1;
                char_ = pseudographics[style()];
            },
            'changeWeight': (dir, w) => {
                weights[dirs[dir]] += w;
                char_ = pseudographics[style()];
            }
        };
    };

    const cells = [];
    let screen = {
        'clear': () => {},
        'putc': () => {}
    };

    const getCell = (i, j) => {
        while (cells.length <= i) {
            cells.push([]);
        }
        const row = cells[i];
        while (row.length <= j) {
            row.push(makeCell());
        }
        return row[j];
    };

    const makeButton = (labels, border) => {
        for (const [i, j, text] of labels) {
            for (let k = 0; k < text.length; ++k) {
                getCell(i, j + k).setChar(text.charAt(k));
            }
        };

        const processBorder = cb => {
            let [pi, pj] = border[border.length - 1];
            for (let k = 0; k < border.length; ++k) {
                const [ni, nj] = border[k];
                if (pi == ni) {
                    const j1 = Math.min(pj, nj);
                    const j2 = Math.max(pj, nj);
                    for (let j = j1; j < j2; ++j) {
                        cb(pi, j, 'r');
                    }
                    for (let j = j1 + 1; j < j2 + 1; ++j) {
                        cb(pi, j, 'l');
                    }
                } else if (pj == nj) {
                    const i1 = Math.min(pi, ni);
                    const i2 = Math.max(pi, ni);
                    for (let i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {
                        cb(i, pj, 'd');
                    }
                    for (let i = i1 + 1; i < i2 + 1; ++i) {
                        cb(i, pj, 'u');
                    }
                }
                [pi, pj] = [ni, nj];
            }
        };

        processBorder((i, j, dir) => {
            const cell = getCell(i, j);
            cell.setLine(dir);
            screen.putc(i, j, cell.getChar());
        });

        const changeWeight = w => {
            processBorder((i, j, dir) => {
                const cell = getCell(i, j);
                cell.changeWeight(dir, w);
                screen.putc(i, j, cell.getChar());
            });
        };
        let down = false;
        const press = () => {
            if (!down) {
                changeWeight(1);
                down = true;
            }
        };
        const release = () => {
            if (down) {
                changeWeight(-1);
                down = false;
            }
        };

        return {
            'press': press,
            'release': release
        };
    };

    const paintKeyboard = () => {
        screen.clear();
        for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
            const row = cells[i];
            for (let j = 0; j < row.length; ++j) {
                const cell = row[j];
                if (cell !== undefined) {
                    screen.putc(i, j, cell.getChar());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        'makeButton': makeButton,
        'h': () => cells.length,
        'w': () => cells.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b.length), 0),
        'attachScreen': screen_ => {
            screen = screen_;
            paintKeyboard();
        }
    };
};

const makeScreen = (parent_, h, w) => {
    const pre = createElement(parent_, 'pre');
    const spans = new Array(h);
    for (let i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        spans[i] = new Array(w);
        for (let j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            const span = createElement(pre, 'span');
            createTextNode(span, ' ');
            spans[i][j] = span;
        }
        createTextNode(pre, '\n');
    }

    return {
        'clear': () => {
            for (const row of spans) {
                for (const span of row) {
                    span.textContent = ' ';
                }
            }
        },
        'putc': (i, j, c) => {
            if (0 <= i && i < spans.length && 0 <= j && j < spans[i].length) {
                spans[i][j].textContent = c;
            }
        }
    };
};

const makeKeyboardBuilder = () => {
    const keyboard = makeKeyboard();

    const buttons = {};

    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;

    const add = label => {
        const tag = label.trim();
        const jj = j + label.length + 1;
        const button = keyboard.makeButton(
            [[i + 1, j + 1, label]], 
            [[i, j], [i, jj], [i + 2, jj], [i + 2, j]]
        );
        if (!(tag in buttons)) {
            buttons[tag] = [];
        }
        buttons[tag].push(button);
        j = jj;
    };

    return {
        'row': labels => labels.forEach(add),
        'crlf': () => { i += 2; j = 0; },
        'space': j_ => j += j_,
        'keyboard': () => keyboard,
        'press': tag => buttons[tag].forEach(b => b.press()),
        'release': tag => buttons[tag].forEach(b => b.release())
    };
};

const main = () => {
    const builder = makeKeyboardBuilder();
    builder.row([
        ' Esc ', 'F1 ', 'F2 ', 'F3 ', 'F4 ', 'F5 ', 'F6 ', 'F7 ', 'F8 ', 'F9 ',
        'F10', 'F11', 'F12', 'Ins ', 'PrSc', ' Del '
    ]);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.row([
        '`~ ', ' 1! ', ' 2@ ', ' 3# ', ' 4$ ', ' 5% ', ' 6^ ', ' 7& ', ' 8* ',
        ' 9( ', ' 0) ', ' -_ ', ' =+ ', ' BkSp'
    ]);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.row([
        'Tab ', ' Q  ', ' W  ', ' E  ', ' R  ', ' T  ', ' Y  ', ' U  ', ' I  ',
        ' O  ', ' P  ', ' [  ', ' ]  ', ' \\| '
    ]);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.row([
        'CpsLck', ' A  ', ' S  ', ' D  ', ' F  ', ' G  ', ' H  ', ' J  ',
        ' K  ', ' L  ', ' ;: ', ' \'" ', ' Enter '
    ]);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.row([
        'Shift   ', ' Z  ', ' X  ', ' C  ', ' V  ', ' B  ', ' N  ', ' M  ',
        ' ,< ', ' .> ', ' /? ', ' Shift    '
    ]);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.row([
        'Ctrl ', ' Fn ', 'Win ', 'Alt ', '                ', 'Alt  ', 'Ctrl  '
    ]);
    builder.space(1);
    builder.row(['PgUp ', ' Up  ', 'PgDn ']);
    builder.crlf();
    builder.space(37);
    builder.row(['Home ', ' End ']);
    builder.space(3);
    builder.row(['Left ', 'Down ', 'Right']);

    const keyboard = builder.keyboard();

    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    const screen = makeScreen(body, keyboard.h(), keyboard.w());
    keyboard.attachScreen(screen);

    const input = {
        'Control': 'Ctrl',
        'Escape': 'Esc',
        'OS': 'Win',
        'Backspace': 'BkSp',
        'Delete': 'Del',
        '`': '`~',
        '1': '1!',
        '2': '2@',
        '3': '3#',
        '4': '4$',
        '5': '5%',
        '6': '6^',
        '7': '7&',
        '8': '8*',
        '9': '9(',
        '0': '0)',
        '-': '-_',
        '=': '=+',
        '\\': '\\|',
        ';': ';:',
        "'": '\'"',
        ',': ',<',
        '.': '.>',
        '/': '/?',
        ' ': '',
        'PageUp': 'PgUp',
        'ArrowUp': 'Up',
        'PageDown': 'PgDn',
        'ArrowLeft': 'Left',
        'ArrowDown': 'Down',
        'ArrowRight': 'Right'
    };
    for (const c of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') {
        input[c] = c.toUpperCase();
        input[c.toUpperCase()] = c.toUpperCase();
    }
    for (const w of ['Shift', 'Alt', 'Tab', '[', ']', 'Enter', 'Home', 'End']) {
        input[w] = w;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) {
        input['F' + i] = 'F' + i;
    }

    body.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        const key = event.key;
        if (key in input) {
            builder.press(input[key]);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    body.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
        const key = event.key;
        if (key in input) {
            builder.release(input[key]);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Screen keyboard</title>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      Click on keyboard. Press Shift-A.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я вот только не понимаю, а зачем вам так много span? Мне кажется, что в web куда быстрее работала бы перерисовка одного pre чем нескольких десятков из тысячи span. А вот в терминале конечно полная перерисовка может начать лагать, да и трафика бы жрала много...

Comment: `Экран` - это только модель. Я не думал об эффективности перерисовки самого экрана. Мне нужен был API который позволяет ставить символы в сетку. Как было короче, так и написал.

Answer (score 3):

Мое предложение: рендерить клавиатуру на основе заданного массива строк кнопок.

```
    const rows = [
        ['Tab    ', ' Q', ' W', ' E', ' R', ' T', ' Y', ' U', ' I', ' O', ' P', ' [', ' ]', '    |'],
        ['CapsLock', ' A', ' S', ' D', ' F', ' G', ' H', ' J', ' K', ' L', ' ;:', ` '"`, ' Enter'],
        ['Shift    ', ' Z', ' X', ' C', ' V', ' B', ' N', ' M', ' ,<', ' .>', ' /?', '   Shift']
    ];
```

В моей реализации важно, чтобы суммарно по символам все строки были одинаковой длины, точнее следующая строка не должна быть длиннее предыдущей.

Я не делал решение для секции, где находится pagedown/pageup, можно попробовать реализовать отступы, ну либо немного переиграть раскладку, например, расположить эти кнопки справа на верхних уровнях.

Самое, наверное, геморное было написать функцию `getSymbolBetweenRows`, в ней, кстати, `info` объект можно заменить на тот же числовой code и тогда весь код легко будет переписать на любой сиподобный язык.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

    const rows = [
        ['Tab    ', ' Q', ' W', ' E', ' R', ' T', ' Y', ' U', ' I', ' O', ' P', ' [', ' ]', '    |'],
        ['CapsLock', ' A', ' S', ' D', ' F', ' G', ' H', ' J', ' K', ' L', ' ;:', ` '"`, ' Enter'],
        ['Shift    ', ' Z', ' X', ' C', ' V', ' B', ' N', ' M', ' ,<', ' .>', ' /?', '   Shift']
    ];

    /**
     * @var Unicode Box Draw Map
     * @usedBy draw()
     */
    const boxDraw = new Map([
        [  1, 116],[  2, 120],[  4, 119],[  5,  16],[  6,  17],[  7,  85],
        [  8, 123],[  9,  18],[ 10,  19],[ 13,  86],[ 15,  87],[ 16, 118],
        [ 17,   0],[ 18, 126],[ 20,  12],[ 21,  44],[ 22,  45],[ 24,  14],
        [ 25,  48],[ 26,  49],[ 28,  83],[ 29, 101],[ 32, 122],[ 33, 124],
        [ 34,   1],[ 36,  13],[ 37,  46],[ 38,  47],[ 40,  15],[ 41,  50],
        [ 42,  51],[ 51,  80],[ 52,  82],[ 55, 100],[ 60,  84],[ 63, 102],
        [ 64, 117],[ 65,  24],[ 66,  25],[ 67,  91],[ 68,   2],[ 69,  36],
        [ 70,  37],[ 71,  97],[ 72, 125],[ 73,  39],[ 74,  42],[ 80,  20],
        [ 81,  52],[ 82,  53],[ 84,  28],[ 85,  60],[ 86,  61],[ 88,  31],
        [ 89,  65],[ 90,  69],[ 96,  21],[ 97,  54],[ 98,  55],[100,  29],
        [101,  62],[102,  63],[104,  34],[105,  70],[106,  72],[112,  88],
        [115, 103],[116,  94],[119, 106],[128, 121],[129,  26],[130,  27],
        [132, 127],[133,  38],[134,  41],[136,   3],[137,  40],[138,  43],
        [144,  22],[145,  56],[146,  57],[148,  30],[149,  64],[150,  67],
        [152,  32],[153,  66],[154,  73],[160,  23],[161,  58],[162,  59],
        [164,  33],[165,  68],[166,  71],[168,  35],[169,  74],[170,  75],
        [193,  92],[195,  93],[204,  81],[205,  98],[207,  99],[208,  89],
        [209, 104],[220,  95],[221, 107],[240,  90],[243, 105],[252,  96],
        [255, 108],
    ]);

    /**
     * @function getSymbolByCode
     * @param {Number} code Must be integer in range [0-255]
     * @returns {String}
     */
    function getSymbolByCode(code) {
        return !code ? ' ' : boxDraw.has(code) ? String.fromCharCode(boxDraw.get(code) + 0x2500) : null;
    }

    const getDefaultDash = () => ({draw: false, bold: false});
    const getDefaultSymbolInfo = () => ({
        top: getDefaultDash(),
        right: getDefaultDash(),
        bottom: getDefaultDash(),
        left: getDefaultDash()
    });

    const getSymbolByInfo = info => {
        let code = 0;
        const directions = ['left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top'];
        for (let i = 0; i < directions.length; i++) {
            const {draw, bold} = info[directions[i]];
            code |= (draw ? 1 + bold : 0) << (i * 2);
        }
        return getSymbolByCode(code);
    }

    const getRowSum = row => {
        return row.reduce((sum, {length}) => sum + length + 2, 0);
    }

    const findKeyByPosition = (row, position) => {
        for (let i = 0, sum = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            let left = sum;
            sum += row[i].length + 2;
            if (position >= left && position <= sum) {
                const result = {
                    value: null,
                    next: null,
                    isDelimiter: false,
                    left,
                    right: sum
                };
                if (position !== 0) {
                    result.value = row[i];
                } else {
                    result.next = row[i];
                }
                if (position === sum) {
                    result.next = row[i + 1];
                }
                result.isDelimiter = position === left || position === sum;
                return result;
            }
        }
        throw "Position is out of bounds";
    }

    const active = new Set();
    const isActive = key => {
        if (!key) {
            return false;
        }
        key = key.trim();
        for (let a of active.keys()) {
            if (key === a || key === a.toUpperCase() || (key.length === 2 && key.includes(a))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    const getSymbolBetweenRows = (topRow, bottomRow, position) => {
        const info = getDefaultSymbolInfo();

        const checkHorizontal = key => {
            if (key.value) {
                info.left.draw = true;
            }
            if (isActive(key.value)) {
                info.left.bold = true;
            }
            if (key.isDelimiter) {
                if (key.next || position === 0) {
                    info.right.draw = true;
                }
                if (isActive(key.next)) {
                    info.right.bold = true;
                }
            } else {
                info.right.draw = true;
                if (isActive(key.value) || isActive(key.next)) {
                    info.right.bold = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (topRow) {
            const top = findKeyByPosition(topRow, position);
            info.top.draw = top.isDelimiter;
            info.top.bold = isActive(top.value) || isActive(top.next);
            checkHorizontal(top);
        }
        if (bottomRow) {
            const bottom = findKeyByPosition(bottomRow, position);
            info.bottom.draw = bottom.isDelimiter;
            info.bottom.bold = isActive(bottom.value) || isActive(bottom.next);
            checkHorizontal(bottom);
        }

        return getSymbolByInfo(info);
    }

    const renderTop = (row, prevRow) => {
        let line = '';
        const sum = getRowSum(row);
        for (let i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
            line += getSymbolBetweenRows(prevRow, row, i);
        }
        return line;
    }

    const renderCenter = (row) => {
        let line = '';
        const sum = getRowSum(row);
        for (let i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
            const current = findKeyByPosition(row, i);
            const info = getDefaultSymbolInfo();
            if (current.isDelimiter) {
                info.top.draw = info.bottom.draw = true;
                info.top.bold = info.bottom.bold = isActive(current.value) || isActive(current.next);
                line += getSymbolByInfo(info);
            } else {
                let value = ' ' + current.value + ' ';
                line += value[i - current.left];
            }
        }
        return line;
    }

    const renderBottom = (row, nextRow) => {
        let line = '';
        const sum = getRowSum(row);
        for (let i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
            line += getSymbolBetweenRows(row, nextRow, i);
        }
        return line;
    }

    const render = (rows) => {
        const lines = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const row = rows[i];
            const prevRow = i > 0 ? rows[i - 1] : null;
            lines.push(renderTop(row, prevRow));
            lines.push(renderCenter(row));
        }
        lines.push(renderBottom(rows[rows.length - 1]));
        container.innerHTML = lines.join('\n');
    }

    render(rows);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        active.add(event.key);
        render(rows);
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
        active.delete(event.key);
        render(rows);
    });
```

```html
<pre id="container"></pre>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если говорить об идеальном... В общем, на данный момент все раскладки известны. Их [формы](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/xkeyboard-config/blob/master/geometry/pc), [коды](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/xkeyboard-config/blob/master/keycodes/xfree86), [вариации](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/xkeyboard-config/blob/master/keycodes/aliases), [подписи клавишь](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/xkeyboard-config/blob/master/symbols/ru) стандартизированы. Не думаю, что появятся какие-либо другие раскладки. Если интересно, можно полазить по остальным файлам. Там можно черпнуть знаний...

Comment: То есть, я немного изменил формы раскладки клавиатуры, что бы таблица клавиатуры поместилась на стандартный размер экрана терминала (80х24) и еще осталось чуть-чуть места. А цель вопроса была в алгоритме, который помог бы выделить нужные клавиши толстой обводкой, например **H J K L**. Ну или любые которые есть...

Comment: @DiD Да, про цель я так и понял, поэтому сделал минимальный рабочий пример именно с демонстрацией выделения.

Comment: Да посмотрел, все работает!

Comment: просто на русской раскладке не работал. )) я и не понял сначала, а потом код посмотрел и понял.

Comment: @DiD на этот счет я тоже не стал заморачиваться: там в моей проверке `isActive` если будут кнопки F1, F2, то они будут выделяться при F и при цифрах =) функция выделения при клике написана только для демонстрации, на деле, как понимаю, необходимо просто рендерить с уже заданными активными кнопками и обработчика клика не будет

Comment: да я бы брал `event.code` вместо `event.key`, но вы правы, это по барабану так как воспроизводиться всё будет в платформе далекой от Web

Comment: @DiD а есть может гитхаб у этого проекта? =) если там будут еще интересные для меня задачи на подобии этой, я бы может взял какое issue =)